# TFS 2015 exception when uploading build task

Tags: tfs-2015

I get this error in the TFS logs when I try to upload a task in the new TFS build system using the `tfx-cli` tool:

```
    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskAgentVersionMismatchException: 
    The task definition being uploaded requires a minimum agent version of 1.88.0. 
The server's agent version is 1.83.2.
```

Unfortunately that is the agent that TFS provides for download.
It is an On Premise TFS server.

Does anyone know how to get the 1.88 version of the agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did modified the task json file and I was able to upload it however it did not show up in the TFS UI.

And the reason is here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/issues/30

In summary I was trying to use IISWebAppDeploy task which from the official git repository but that task is still in development and it will not show up in TFS until marked for release.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose 1.88 is the current version of the VSO build agents. At least if I login to my VSO project and switch to the Hosted pool, the hosted agent is of version 1.88. I suspect it is being upgraded by the VSO silently. Thus, if you download an agent from VSO one of these days, it will most likely have version 1.88.

However, I'm not sure it is a good idea. First verify whether you really need a more recent version. The `minimalAgentVersion` is defined in the custom task definition, the JSON file. Try changing it down to your agent version, 1.83.2. Most likely, you should not require a higher version of the agent in your custom task until you upgrade your TFS instance.